# Can I use mocks in testing Flask app functions?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I'm trying to test some routes on my Flask app that call external APIs, which I want to mock.

The routes are set up like this:

```
@app.route('/url/<string::arg>')
def route_function(arg):
    data = external_api(arg)
    response = make_response(data)
    # configure response
    return response
```

I originally tried something like this:

```
class TestFlaskApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()

    @patch('external_api',
           side_effect=mock_api)
    def test_flask_route(self, api):
        result = app.get('/url/arg')
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
        api.assert_called_once_with('arg')
```

...which failed. The mock API function wasn't called, since I assume the mock does not apply in the app context.

I also tried this, thinking I might be able to test the route functions directly and thus avoid having to use the app context:

```
class TestAppFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('external_api',
           side_effect=mock_api)
    def test_flask_function(self, api):
        result = my_flask_app.route_function('arg')
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
        api.assert_called_once_with('arg')
```

...but this didn't work either, since to make a response, `route_function` needs the app context.

So is there a way to mock inside the app context? How else can I test these routes without triggering external API calls?

Comment: You need to pass the object path to the patch function so that it can be resolved and replaced with the mock at runtime. For example if `external_api` function is called in a module named `routes` which is in turn contained in a package named `my_shining_app`, patch will be passed `my_shining_app.routes.external_api`. I hope this clears this up.

Comment: In my code I have the complete path to the function (e.g., `@patch('containingmodule.external_api')` and it still doesn't work. The mock function never gets called.

Comment: Note that the path should be where the function is called (i.e. where it's to be replaced with the mock) and not where it's defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Oluwafemi Sule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5189811/oluwafemi-sule) was right...I just needed to patch the function where it was used, not where it was defined.

> You need to pass the object path to the patch function so that it can be resolved and replaced with the mock at runtime. For example if `external_api function` is called in a module named `routes` which is in turn contained in a package named `my_shining_app`, patch will be passed as `my_shining_app.routes.external_api`
>
> Note that the path should be where the function is called (i.e. where it's to be replaced with the mock) and not where it's defined

Comment: An example to be clear, because I had to read it twice before getting it right: imagine you have imported `myfunc` from `mymodule.py` in `main.py`. You have to patch `main.myfunc` with utnittest for it to work. Not `mymodule.myfunc`.